# JS Conditional Regex replace for Link

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, string

I am identifying links in a text using regex and replacing them with a href link. The problem that I am facing is that I need to navigate links with www. differently than https:// and for that I have to use conditional check.

I am inserting // before the url to make it relative to the protocol of my website. so links like www would be appended next to the network portocol of the site.

Following is the code and the *problem* is that I can not insert the url dynamically in href. I hvae tried several template interpolations but somehow that is not working.
Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

```
            var exp = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;
            return params.value?.replace(exp, (link) => {

              if (!link.startsWith('http')) {
               return "<a href='//`${link}`' target='_blank' rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">`${link}`</a>"
              }
              return "<a href='`${link}`' target='_blank' rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">`${link}`</a>"

            }
```

Comment: I can't say about the rest but for sure the template literals are malformed. Those strings should be delimited with backticks and no need to escape the double quotes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
for example: `\`<a href='//${link}' target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">${link}</a>\``

Comment: Why would you want to insert `//` before `https`? That will make the URL invalid. Can you edit your question and provide examples of how the replacements should turn out?

Comment: If your regex requires the url to start with "http", why would you test that indeed the link starts with "http" in the `if` condition? That condition will always be the same. Can you edit your question and provide **examples** of what you hope to match, and what should be produced for each of them?

Comment: regex doesn't requires it to start always with http, they can also be starting with www as mentioned in regex as well. 

so lets say a random string like hello www.google.com and hi https:// google.com should be replace these link texts to actual links while keeping everything else same. The reason for condition is to resolve both links with www and http in different way to ensure they both work when clicked by user

Answer (score 0):

Probably the main problem in your code is how you crafted the strings holding the anchors html. Template literals should be delimited with backticks and no need to escape the double quotes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
return `<a href='//${link}' target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">${link}</a>`
return `<a href='${link}' target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">${link}</a>`
```

Anyway this is a more elaborate a demo showing how to parse the urls coming from an input textarea control and append the corresponding anchors to a target element.

At first it parses the textarea content (prefilled with a string) looking for urls (using your own regex) and then uses those urls to craft a new anchor element for each one and appends it to the target element.

***as stated in the original comments, I rewrote the template literals holding the logic to craft the html for the anchors***.

```js
//on document ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  //adjust the textarea height according to its content
  const params = document.getElementById('params');
  params.style.height = "1px";
  params.style.height = (params.scrollHeight) + 'px';
});

//adds a click event listener to the #trigger element button
document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  //that will create and append an anchor to #target when pressing the button
  createAndShowAnchor();
});

//parses the url value and returns a string containing html to render the corresponding anchor
function parseUrl(url){    
  //if the url starts with http
  if (!url.startsWith('http'))
    return `<a href='//${url}' target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">${url}</a>`;
  //otherwise
  else
    return `<a href='${url}' target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">${url}</a>`;
}

//creates an anchor according to the url written on the input text and appends it to #target
function createAndShowAnchor(){  
  //fetches the input element
  const params = document.getElementById('params');      
  //grabs the value typed inside the textarea
  const rawtext = params.value;
  //parse the urls contained in the text
  const urls = parseUrls(rawtext);
  
  //fetches and empties the target element
  const target = document.getElementById('target');
  target.innerHTML = '';
  
  //for each url extracted
  for(let url of urls){  
    //create the html for an anchor holding such url
    const anchorHTML = parseUrl(url);      
    //creates the anchor element (using a dirty trick)  
    const temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = anchorHTML;
    const anchor = temp.firstChild;
    //appends the newly created anchor to target    
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(anchor);
    target.appendChild(li);  
  }  
}

//given a subject, returns all the string containing an url
function parseUrls(subject){
  const re = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/img;
  let match = re.exec(subject);  
  const urls = [];
  while (match != null) {  
    urls.push(match[0]);
    match = re.exec(subject);    
  }
  return urls;
}
```

```css
#params{
  width: 40em;
}

#target{
  border: dashed  2px darkgray;    
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;  
  list-style: none;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="params">text where to parse for urls:</label>
<br>
<textarea id="params">
http://asdf.com
bogus
notanurl
https://asdf.com
</textarea>
<br>
<button id="trigger" type="button">ADD</button>

<ul id="target">  
</ul>
```

Comment: The regex is used to find out the links in the text and then replace them with href links. Thats why I am using replace. what I am doing afterwards is to conditionally deal with different types of links. I am doing this in AG grid in angular and its not just plain html stuff rather more dynamic things. So thats why I can select html elements like this and have to therefore, do the changes in TS file.

Comment: I changed the logic so that the input it's a textarea containing mixed text that will be parsed upfront looking for urls that will be handled as before. I think there's the whole logic you may find useful for your goal. If you need to go further I'll need further details and more clarity

Comment: Sorry this was rather a silly mistake. the comment that you put up was what solved it. Please add it in your solution so I can mark it as correct. Thank you! :D

Comment: I better stressed the template literals mistake and formatted in bold the last line that was already there to better highlight the fact I included that modification already in the demo